# Firebase: How to get array back rather than objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a call to get a list of `books` I have setup in firebase with this call

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + uid + '/books').on('value', (data) => {
   this.books = data.val();
})
```

The data is coming back as an Object with the book objects inside though.  I need them in an array form because my table takes an array to display the data.  Is there a way to get it back in an array form without transforming the data?  I anticipate the list getting really long so transforming the data would seem like a performance issue eventually.

[image: screenshot of firebase db]

Comment: Can you give details on what is json format you are receiving as "data.val()"? and what is required format?

Comment: @SivaKondapiVenkata sure, it's coming back as `{-LxAOIiTml3AE9c_4wxg: {…}, -LxAOL_n_KSmNa_1JdPQ: {…}}` .  I want it to come back as an Array of Objects, not an Object with the Objects inside like : `[{-LxAOIiTml3AE9c_4wxg: {…}, -LxAOL_n_KSmNa_1JdPQ: {…}}]`

Comment: Got it @morganOril, I just added answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go over the Object keys and convert to Array of Objects using map.

```js
var obj = { a:  { b : 2 }, c:  { b : 2 } };

var arr_obj = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({ [key]: obj[key] }));

console.log(arr_obj)
```

Comment: thanks but I'm concerned with this not scaling with a large dataset.  I have to map through the data each time I make the call then

Comment: Ohh ok @morganOril got it!. Just going thru https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html. It says "Firebase has no native support for arrays", If So, some one (backend or frontend) has to convert from Obj -> Array.

Comment: I ran into this yesterday... with [`.on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) you open a subscription and [`.once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) will get you "one" call. If you opt to use `once` it will return a Promise so you could format the data there and await your finished data set

Comment: darn, that's a shame!   thanks @siva for finding that!

Comment: @SivaKondapiVenkata Firebase definitely has support for arrays in both the Real Time Database as well as Firestore. However, they are treated as an object, so when you call .val() or use the REST api to read data, if the data looks like an array, Firebase will render it as an array. The key though, is that Arrays are often not ideal for using with NoSQL databases and there are often much better options. Probably a good idea to read through that entire post as posing it does not support arrays is out of context